# error reading a large binary file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io, binaryfiles, large-files

I have to read in a large Binary file whose size is 92,504 KB. When I am using fread command MATLAB is giving me error:

> Error using fread Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

I tried to restart MATLAB also so that if I am using any virtual memory it should be cleared but still the problem persists.

How can I solve this problem of reading data.

Comment: did you type "help memory"?

Comment: yes I typed help memory but could not understand what to do after it.

Comment: Right, the idea is to use the `memory` command to see that matlab has enough memory space available to fit the data you want to read. Your file is only 92mb (or there abouts) so it shouldn't be taking up enough space to get out of memory. Could you post the code you are using to read the file?

Comment: Below is the MATLAB code I am using for reading the binary file                                                                 fid = fopen('dump_20_master.dump','r');
[data,count] = fread(fid,'uint8');

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the code that you are using to read the data:

```
[data,count] = fread(fid,'uint8');
```

The above line tells matlab to read in as many `uint8s` as it can and put them into a vector.

The trouble is that matlab will put it into a vector of doubles. So rather than a vector where each element is one byte, you have a vector where each element is 8 bytes. This ends up making your 92Mb of data take up 92*8 = 736mb which is probably going to be bigger than the maximum possible array size shown by the `memory` command.

The solution here is to tell matlab to put the data you are reading into a vector of `uint8` which can be achieved as follows:

```
[data,count] = fread(fid,'*uint8');
```

This method for reading in the data tells matlab that the output vector should be the same type as the input data. You can read more about it in the precision section of the [fread documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fread.html).

Answer (score 1):

In a 32-bit system, you may have very less memory available to MATLAB. The fread command you are using reads the entire file at once. This is probably a bad idea, since you system is not having enough memory. A better way to implement would be to read file part by part. See,
   `A = fread(fileID, sizeA)` 
in link below[1]. You can put this code inside a loop. In case you want to read whole file at once, what i would recommend is to use a 64-bit system with 3GB RAM.

[1] http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/fread.html